# Simple C number formatting

Tags: c, formatting, floating-point, numbers, printf

This a very simple c question.

Is there a way to format a float for printf so that it has xx SIGNIFICANT decimals?

So I'm not talking about, say, `%5.3f` float, but if I had

```
float x=0.00001899383
```

How would I output 0.0000189 if I wanted *up to* the first three non-zero decimals?

Comment: Note that your example number to 3 significant figures is 0.0000190

Answer (score 10):

"%.3g" will try to output three significant digits, either in scientific or fixed format.

at bjg:

The program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  double a = 123456789e-15;
  int i = 0;
  for( i=-10; i <= 10; ++i )
  {
    printf("%.3g\n", a );
    a *= 10;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

outputs

```
1.23e-07
1.23e-06
1.23e-05
0.000123
0.00123
0.0123
0.123
1.23
12.3
123
1.23e+03
1.23e+04
1.23e+05
1.23e+06
1.23e+07
1.23e+08
1.23e+09
1.23e+10
1.23e+11
1.23e+12
1.23e+13
```

Comment: But that wouldn't deal with the non-zero part of the question. This will just the format first 3 digits regardless

Comment: @bjg, no, it prints 3 **significant** digits, but will use exponential notation if there are more than a couple leading zeros..

Comment: Peter, thanks! I'm actually just doing a couple c functions within an Obj-C app and had forgotten this stuff for a long time.

like Jamie said, +1 + +1